# Como pegar cookie de sessão via javascript?

Tags: javascript, front-end

Preciso fazer um script que quando o usuário chegar na minha utm via url, eu devo gravar um cookie de sessão. Esse cookie irá expirar quando o browser fechar. Alguem consegue me ajudar com isto?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para criar um cookie de *sessão*, basta associar uma string contendo o formato `chave=valor` à propriedade `cookie` de `document`:

```
document.cookie = "[nomeDoCookie]=[ValorDoCookie]";
```

Caso você deseje persistir este cookie entre sessões do browser, você pode especificar uma data de expiração em format *GMTString*:

```
document.cookie = "[nomeDoCookie]=[ValorDoCookie]; expires=[data]";
```

Exemplos:

```
document.cookie = "cookie2=sample";
document.cookie = "cookie2=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT";
```

Entretanto vale a pena mencionar que não existe guarantia de que o cookie de sessão será dispensado quando todas as janelas forem fechadas - o Chrome, por exemplo, possui uma configuração que *por padrão* mantém os cookies de sessão vivos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fontes:
MDN - [Document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie)
StackOverflow - [Chrome doesn't delete session cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10772420/1845714)

Answer (score 3):

Use o plugin

http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

**Criar**

```
$.cookie("exemplo", "abc");
$.cookie("exemplo", "abc", { expires: 7 }); 
$.cookie("exemplo", "abc", { path: '/admin', expires: 7 });
```

**Ler**

```
alert( $.cookie("exemplo") );
```

**Remover**

```
$.removeCookie("exemplo");
```

Fonte:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599287/create-read-and-erase-cookies-with-jquery

Answer (score 2):

Para criar o cookie:

```
  document.cookie = "username=[utilizador]; expires=[dia que expira], [18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC]";
```

Para ler o cookie:

```
var x = document.cookie;
```

Answer (score 2):

Marcos,

de acordo com [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_cookie), para fazer o que você pretende deve ser criado um session cookie, que nada mais é do que um cookie sem data de expiração.

Quando se cria o cookie sem data de expiração, ele fica apenas na memória e assim que o browser é fechado o cookie é removido.

> A session cookie, also known as an in-memory cookie or transient cookie, exists only in temporary memory while the user navigates the website.[12] Web browsers normally delete session cookies when the user closes the browser.[13] Unlike other cookies, session cookies do not have an expiration date assigned to them, which is how the browser knows to treat them as session cookies.